# If ($f_n$) is Cauchy in measure, there exists a subsequence ($g_k$) of ($f_n$) such that ($g_k$) converges a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> [image]

This is the proof that if $(f_n)$ is cauchy in measure, there exists a subsequence $(g_k)$ of $(f_n)$ such that $(g_k)$ converges a.e. (from Bartle). I just don't understand one step in this proof. I thought that he uses a geometric series, but I couldn't figure out. Could you explain how the inequality of the red line holds?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $x\notin F_k$, while $F_k = \bigcup_{j \geqslant k} E_k$ where $E_k$ gives an inequality above, so what could you deduce about $|g_i - g_{i-1}|$ etc.?

Comment: Thanks for comment. But, I don't really get your hint. I know that $|g_i - g_{i-1}| \le 1/2^{i-1}$, but I don't understand $1/2^{i-1}+...+1/2^j <1/2^{j-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your question. The last inequality is a sum of geometric progression, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as you said. For the geometric series $ c\sum_{n=0}^N 2^n $, with $c>0$, note the explicit formula immediately gives

$$ c\sum_{n=0}^N 2^n = c\frac{2^{N+1}-1}{2 - 1} \le c2^{N+1} $$

For you, we have $N=i-j-1$, $c=2^{-i+1}$, giving

$$ 2^{-i+1} + \dots + 2^{-j} \le 2^{-i+1} 2^{i-j} = 2^{-j+1}$$

Note that the above doesn't cover the case $i=j$, but in this case, the inequality $0=|g_i(x) - g_j(x)|\le \frac1{2^j}$ is trivial.

Comment: I Get it. thanks!